# share post on facebook android

Tags: android, facebook

I have created an app using the Facebook SDK.

It sucessefully logs in to my Facebook account and posts a message on my wall. Now I want to share the post, I have the post/feed id of that post as well, but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

```
String response = mFacebook.request("me");
Bundle parameters = new Bundle(); 
parameters.putString("message", "abcd"); 
response = mFacebook.request("me/photos", parameters, "POST");
```

The code posts the message on my wall, but now I want to implement the share functionality for already posted feeds. I'm getting the feed id of the required feed to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you will have to use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). [Heres](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#graphapicall) the API call for the same.

Have you ever tried sharing anything on facebook? Firstly, you can share only links or photos, you just cant directly share a post that you posted. And when you click on a share button, you get a dialog which is nothing but a Feed Dialog. And that dialog code is given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). The exact java android code that you are looking for is given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/).

Comment: i want to do this in android.

Comment: I understand that, try using the 2nd link, make a call to the graph API, make a post request as given https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#graphapicall

Comment: thanku for the reply . but can u plz provide the java code example

Comment: i have the post id of the post i want to share and have sucessfully login to facebook ... now i want to share that specific post friom my account

Comment: The exact code that you want is given here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

Comment: in this code they are sharing by making a message using bundle like name,caption,discription etc but i only have the post id of the post i want to share

Comment: u r right i m already done with this and got the post id but know i want to share the post again and i only have post id how can i share using the post id